# Office 365 Integration on Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-office-365

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 that is a Domain Controller and was originally setup with Office 365 integration. Lately it would not sync and would not let me re-link to the Office 365 Account.

I have disabled the integration for O365 and Azure Active Directory. When I attempt to setup the O365 again it says to check to make sure the computer is connected to the internet. I have tried through power shell with the following error.

Enable-O365Integration : Connect to BECWS failed.

Comment: `I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 that was originally setup with Office 365 integration` - What exactly does that mean? Do you mean that you're running Azure AD Connect on the server?

Comment: @joeqwerty - The server is a domain controller and the Azure AD was automaticly setup 3 years ago when the O365 integration was setup. They are linked.

Comment: OK. I just wanted to clarify what you meant.

Comment: Can you try without IPv6? Try disabling it from the Nic and try again. You will be able to find the details in the event log as well.

Comment: @epoxy Sorry I forgot to include it but I did disable IPv6 from the NIC and disabled the secondary NIC. Ill look in the event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been caused by Microsoft changing something on their Office 365 relay servers. If you're seeing an endpoint error in the "SharedServiceHost-EmailProviderServiceConfig.log" file, you can delete the invalid server address from the registry:

https://exchangemaster.wordpress.com/2018/03/14/windows-server-essentials-o365-integration-errors/

> I was able to trace the error message to this Microsoft forum post where MVP Susan Bradley provided the resolution. In this case, the resolution was to navigate to the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Server\Productivity\O365Integration\Settings** registry key and delete or rename the “**BecEndPointAddress**” registry entry.

Deleting that registry key and restarting all Essentials services should allow you to change the integration settings again the next time you open the Dashboard.

Comment: this has resolved the problem. Did not see an endpoint error but it worked. Thank you.